# Different colors for different Texts in the same TextView

Tags: text, colors

I want to give the colors for the text like black color for the heading and brown color for the body-text the problem is these two texts are in same Text-view.
Is there any possible solution for this problem ?

Comment: No solution in sight -- since you did meither mention nor tag-mention the language, GUI toolkit or technology you try to solve this for.

Comment: thanks for the help.i use android xml.

Comment: Then please edit your question, browse for and add suitable tags. Also post a sample of what you have (code!), and describe in detail what you want.

Comment: I don´t know about Android implementation details. In some toolkits, you could define a custom "paint" handler which replaces the defaul painting process.

Comment: And let me add the question: Why don´t you simply create separate text views for header and body? Or alternatively, why don´t you use a text view variant (like a RichEdit, or HtmlView control) where you can embed formatting info into the text shown so that header and body text appear in different colors?

Comment: there is a background for that heading and sub fields when i use separate textviews it will appear as two sections....

Comment: did not get this. Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: can't post screenshot because of less reputation